# Prevent users being logged out frequently when using JWT with short TTL

Tags: jwt

Is it recommended to periodically refresh a JSON Web Token for a user that is active?

I read that it's best practice for tokens to be issued with short expiry dates. However, if the token becomes invalid after 30 minutes, the user would have to re-authenticate regularly. This interruption could become frustrating.

How best to handle this?

Comment: Issue both a refresh token and an access token, and when the access token expires automatically generate a new one using the refresh token.

Comment: Thanks @BrianDriscoll. What's the difference between each? Do they contain different claims?

Comment: The refresh token is used purely as a means to obtain a new access token, so it is often an opaque token that is stored server side and any claims or other metadata (like refresh token exp date) are stored separate from the refresh token. However, that is just convention. There are few, if any, standards around refresh tokens as far as I know.